# Custom Created Window Getting Closed Automatically By Selecting Contextual Menu Option Automatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode7, nsmenu

I have builded a custom window; in this window I am showing nsbuttons.
I am showing a contextual menu if button clicked.
The problem is I don't want to close my window but somehow mouse exited event is getting triggered as soon as I choose option from nsmenu.

I want to prevent this effect.
I am not able to figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance

```
-(void)rightMouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
     NSMenu *theMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Contextual Menu"];

            [[theMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Remove From List" action:@selector(removeWithIdentifier) keyEquivalent:@""] setTarget:self];
            [[theMenu addItemWithTitle:@"Open" action:@selector(openAppWithIdentifier) keyEquivalent:@""] setTarget:self];

            [theMenu popUpMenuPositioningItem:nil atLocation:NSMakePoint(self.bounds.size.width-20, self.bounds.size.height-10) inView:self];
}

-(void)removeWithIdentifier
{
     //My custom view is getting mouse exited event from here
     //I want prevent it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey Friends I have got the answer.

I have found that If your window level is "NSPopUpMenuWindowLevel" and its
view has implemented any context menu over it then this view will always gets mouse exited event.

posting it for future reference.

thanks.